# Refresh GUI when a status changes

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

On a SubForm, a hidden field carrying a status flag is changed at runtime. The content of the form has to change accordingly. When I call RefreshHideFormulas on the UIDocument, the GUI doesn't change. The documentation says that this method take effect only when the user exists the current field, which is indeed happening when I do that manually.

But I need the GUI to be updated automatically after the status changes. I tried this:

```
Sub RefreshHideFormulas
    Call uidoc.RefreshHideFormulas()
    Call uidoc.GotoNextField
    Call uidoc.GotoPrevField
End Sub
```

But it didn't work either!

I their a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.idea.ch/help/help85_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/22c76fefe712502ec1257626005457eb!OpenDocument). I just made the thing more complicated that it is because I've read in the wrong direction. The solution (posted here for the record) is as simple as calling refresh instead of RefreshHideFormulas:

```
Call uidoc.Refresh
```